# Specified text On File Upload Control's Browse Button

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a web form that include Asp.net File Upload Control to Upload a file.
Can I replace the text("Browse..") of FileUploadControl's browse button to some text ("...") or a picture.
Is it possible?I am looking for good solution to overcome this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't change `Browse` text. You may use jQuery [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) plugins.

Comment: Thanks,now I try with some plugins.It is impossible with simple file upload control and css.

Answer (score 0):

File Upload control renders as `<input type="file" name="somename" />`  on the client side, the access to which is heavily guarded by all major browsers, due to the obvious security reasons.

there are many third party controls which use technologies like flash, that will enable you to do what you want, you can do a simple Google search for flash file upload for asp.net to see various components

Comment: Thank you for your interest and answers.